# How to check if a (possibly obfuscated) class exists without showing in logs

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to check if a class exists in runtime.

Using `Class.forName( "com.class.Name" );` is not an option since the class I want to check may be obfuscated using proguard.

Another option is using a `try-catch(NoClassDefFoundError)` block and trying to access the actual class, but this results in the following logs:

- `art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class` on newer os versions with ART - which I was able to avoid by doing `Class cls = CheckedClass.class` surrounded with a `try-catch` from a different method.
- `dalvikvm: Could not find class...` on older os versions using dalvik - which I haven't yet figured out a way to avoid. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you configure proguard to retain that class?

Comment: Not really. My code is in a library and I want to support both options (with and without proguard) without asking the developer to add more proguard rules.